# Best practice to implement enable/disable feature + type of feature

Tags: android

I would like to have some feedback on which is a preferable preference design. We have an enable/disable feature (Stock alert), and type of feature after enabling (Stock alert type).

So far, in 1st design, we present it in the following ways

[image]

[image]

In our 2nd design, we are having the following.

[image]

[image]

**I was wondering, which is better?**

For 1st design, it is

- Good in the sense that, user required 1 step to enable/ disable a feature.
- Bad is that, we are having 2 items in main preference screen.

For 2nd design, it is
 - Good in the sense that, we only have 1 item in main preference screen.
 - Bad is that, user required 2 steps to enable/ disable a feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first solution has two main advantages: You can easily enable/disable the function with a single click and have a more obviously visualisation of the current status. You can always notice a checkbox in less time then reading a text, even if this is a real short one.

To prevent the user from just noticing the alert type but missing that he has to enable it first, I prefer to show the alert type only when alerts are enabled.